# Save rows not selected by dplyr::sample_frac()

Tags: r, dplyr, cross-validation

Does dplyr provide a way to save the rows that were not selected by sample_frac() in addition to the ones that were selected?

Comment: I presume adding a column with the original row position is not what you want?

Comment: @VincentBonhomme Ya, that seems a little cumbersome..

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work... maybe you want to `split` so you get a list of two data frames?

Comment: `train <- mtcars %>% sample_frac(0.2); test <- setdiff(mtcars, train);` ? You're probably better off using `library(caret)` or something more traditional.

Answer (score 0):

I think `dplyr::anti_join()` might be what you're looking for.

Say you have a dataset, and you use `sample_frac` to randomly select 80% of it:

```
> small_data
          car_model  mpg
1         Mazda RX4 21.0
2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0
3        Datsun 710 22.8
4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4
5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7

> training <- small_data %>% sample_frac(0.8)

> training
          car_model  mpg
1         Mazda RX4 21.0
2 Hornet Sportabout 18.7
3        Datsun 710 22.8
4     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0
```

You can save the rows not selected into another dataset using `anti_join`. Here I specify that I want to use "car_model" as the unique identifier:

```
validation <- small_data %>% anti_join(training, by="car_model")

> validation
       car_model  mpg
1 Hornet 4 Drive 21.4
```